# How to prefill the command prompt with some chars?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, jscript, wsh

In a batch file, I want to open a command prompt (and keep it open), and prefill the command with the text "git clone", so I just need to copy a project's URL.

This is how I open a command-prompt and add git to the environment variables (no admin rights):

foo.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
if NOT "%1"=="" goto PROGRAM
cmd /k foo.bat DONT_CLOSE_PROMPT
EXIT

:PROGRAM 
SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\Programme\Git\bin
d:
cd "D:\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects"
REM cls
REM bar.bat
```

This is how to add the text to the command prompt:

bar.bat

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
rem Enter the prefill value in the keyboard buffer
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "git clone "
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

But apparently I can't just copy bar.bat in place of REM bar.bat in foo.bat.

> Compilation error in Microsoft JScript: Conditional compilation is
>   switched off.

D:\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects>
How can I do this (I don't want to have 2 files) ?

Note: echo doesn't cut it, as I need to be able to insert the URL for git clone before pressing enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the batch script inside the conditional compilation block:

bar.bat

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
    if NOT "%1"=="" goto PROGRAM
        cmd /k bar.bat DONT_CLOSE_PROMPT
        EXIT

    :PROGRAM 
    set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
    SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\Programme\Git\bin
    d:
    cd "D:\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects"
    REM cls
    %SendKeys% "git clone "

goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: Some explanation of the code would be useful to people visiting this question for the first time, just saying *"Try"* isn't helpful.