# Windows Batch File is invoking the NumLocks key for some reason

Tags: batch-file

I need to open up cmd.exe in a specific folder (for example: "C:\My Project") and have the Command Prompt prefilled with `blah.exe` . Just to be clear about this, I don't need `blah.exe` executed, I just need to have the Command Prompt prefilled with those characters. I had to do a lot of digging and searching on this but I was able to find a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651887/how-to-prefill-the-command-prompt-with-some-chars) that matched my problem very closely.

I literally just copied & pasted that into Notepad and created teo separate batch files `foo.bat` and `bar.bat`. The only thing I changed was of course the characters I wanted to appear within the Command Prompt, *(in my case `blah.exe` )*.

The script works perfectly fine, except for one annoying thing. Whenever I launch `foo.bat`, it invokes the NumLocks key on my keyboard.

I only know the basics of Windows batch files. Can anyone take a look at these files and see how, or where, this NumLocks key is being invoked?

Contents of `foo.bat`

```bash
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
    if NOT "%1"=="" goto PROGRAM
        cmd /k foo.bat DONT_CLOSE_PROMPT
        EXIT

    :PROGRAM 
    set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
    %SendKeys% "blah.exe "

goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Contents of `bar.bat`

```bash
@ECHO OFF
if NOT "%1"=="" goto PROGRAM
cmd /k bar.bat DONT_CLOSE_PROMPT
EXIT
```

I tried modifying:

```
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
```

to:

```
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%F0" or "%0"
```

but both attempts failed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just finally realized what is going on.  I use a program called AutoHotKeys.  One of the scripts that I use on a regular basis is to start my browser and go to a specific URL1, pause, open URL 2 and login there.  I have programmed it so that the <kbd>NumLocks</kbd> key is the hotkey to invoke the script.  Since this script is always loaded in system memory, when the DOS batch file is launched, the <kbd>NumLocks</kbd> key is invoked when it runs into this line of code:

```
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
```

I just need to re-write the AHK script so a different hotkey is used.

=========================================

However, I still don't understand how the tilde (`~`) is invoking the <kbd>NumLocks</kbd> key in my batch file.  When I remove it, the problem does not happen.  However, removing the `~` from my batch file breaks the code and does not produce the desired result.

Still confused!